# Is this due to loose typed nature of PHP or something else?

Tags: php, variables

Why this kind of difference in output. Is it due to loosey typed PHP or other?

```
<?php
    //optional_argu.php
    function add($one, $two, $three="") //optional argu
    {
        echo $one + $two + $three.'<br />';
    }

    add(040, 20);
    add(40, 20);
?>
```

Outputs: 
52
60
WHY?

Comment: Please learn about octal number notation - 040 is equal to 32, there you have your results.

Comment: Numbers with leading zero are interpreted as if they are in octal numeric system, in most programming languages. This means the `040` number is the octal representation of the integer `32`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A leading `0` in a numeric literal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.syntax) means the number is in [*octal* notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). The number `040` is 32 in decimal.

Comment: Yes I got it, and 0x represent Hexadecimal numbers